# <a> tag does not link to other page

Tags: jquery, html

I created a one page layout and multiple section and added links to the navbar for those sections and I have a jQuery for smooth scrolling withing the page . But if I want to link to other pages it simply does not work and when I remove the Jquery it works just fine.

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
 });
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#hero">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="service.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-form">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Your JQuery will be applied for all `a` tags in your page. If you want to restrict this to your navigation, you can change it to: `$("#myNavbar").on('click', 'a', function(event){`

Answer (score 2):

This will prevent the link from working as normal:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

I'd recommend putting a class on the links that are **anchors** and updating your jQuery to target those classes. *Don't include the class on links you want to link to the other page*

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#hero" class="anchor-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="service.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact-form" class="anchor-link">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about-us" class="anchor-link">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>


$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.anchor-link', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding click event to all link elements, not just links within the same page. Change your selector so that it only captures links with fragments:

```
...
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*="#"]', function(event){
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if you add any class to `<a>` that contains #link and then pimp you JS like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.CHOSEN_CLASS').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
 });
```